# Translating Haskell to C for use on iPhone

Tags: ios, haskell, code-translation

I've written a Haskell library I would like to include in an iPhone app.  It makes heavy use of Haskell's functional abilities, currying, etc. and rewriting in Objective-C would be tough.

Is it possible to automatically translate Haskell to C? or dig out an intermediate C representation from one of the compilers?

Apple's developer agreement forbids statically linking one of the lightweight Haskell interpreters, not that I'm keen on that solution.

Comment: "Apple's developer agreement forbids statically linking one of the lightweight Haskell interpreters" -- Not anymore, I think. The only thing it forbids is running *downloaded* code. However, as long as the code comes from *inside* your app (i.e. it is part of your submission to the App Store), they don't care *how* you execute it. That stupid "only C, C++, Objective-C and ECMAScript" restriction was removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used it but there is
http://projects.haskell.org/ghc-iphone/

Answer (score 4):

http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/ compiles to fairly standard C.  It might be possible to use it.

Comment: But beware that it may be very slow if you make excessive use of laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ghc-ios project:

http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1lboh4/announcing_ghc_ios/